# dv6000 wireless card wont turn on in 11.04

Tags: wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working)

0
down vote
favorite
share [fb]
share [tw]
Just installed 11.04 beta 2 on my HP dv6000 laptop with broadcom wireless. Drivers are installed and system says they are "currently in use" but I can't get wireless to turn on or connect, in 10.10 it did it automatically. Is there a way to turn it on that I'm just missing because of new system?
i just copied and pasted some one who has the same problem as

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/168055/wireless-does-not-work-on-hp-dv6000-with-a-bcm4311 or [How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working) or http://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312

Answer (score 1):

Am using the same model because my girlfriend has the same one. Am using Ubuntu 11.04 **100% RELEASE EDITION** not BETA. It is working perfect so i highly recommend to install Ubuntu 11.04 which was released already. Do not update from Beta to Final Release just to avoid any problem, Just install it from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10527475&postcount=5) helped me.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @izx While it's not necessarily always wrong to comment with a link, link-only answers [really aren't comments and shouldn't usually exist as comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2281/22949). A comment cannot be expanded, edited to fix a broken link, or voted on. Instead, as Stephen Myall has said, this is an answer that would be much better if it included more information than just a link. Sometimes a link-only answer should be removed, but it would only make sense for it to be a comment if the linked page doesn't answer the question but is somehow still valuable.