# How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working?

Tags: wireless, broadcom

Wireless was worked perfectly in ubuntu 10.10. Now I upgraded it to ubuntu 11.04. After this upgrade wireless is not working in my laptop, even "wireless connection" is not showing in network connection list.

What I have to do for this?

`lspci` output:

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
```