# WiFi does not work, Broadcom STA Wireless driver does not work on a BCM4313

Tags: 11.04, wireless, broadcom, lenovo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

I'm newbie in Linux and Ubuntu, but would like to improve my skills :)

I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my laptop (LENOVO B560, dualboot Windows 7 64-bit) and have got an issue with wireless connection - it doesn't work under Ubuntu.

My wireless adapter is Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n.
I had installed Broadcom STA wireless driver, but it doesn't fix my problem - wireless network is disabled - I can't enable it.
I've got a message:

> driver is activated but not currently in use.

It would be great if someone could help me to solve it.

Below is the output of the command `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f2500000-f2503fff
```