# Firmware missing for Broadcom 802.11b/g Adapter?

Tags: 11.10, broadcom, firmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get the Broadcom BCM4306 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44659/how-do-you-get-the-broadcom-bcm4306-wireless-card-working)

I have a HP Pavilion zx5280us laptop (it says HP Pavilion zx5000 on the physical laptop but it's really an HP Pavilion zx5280us when detected on the HP website) and I installed Ubuntu 11.10 alongside Windows XP Professional x86. I tried to use a wireless connection but it said "device not ready (firmware missing)". Any help on this? Here's the code output:

```
00:14.4 PCI bridge [0604]: ATI Technologies Inc IXP200 3COM 3C920B Ethernet Controller [1002:4342]
00:14.5 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: ATI Technologies Inc IXP150 AC'97 Audio Controller [1002:4341]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:006b]
--
02:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4320] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Broadcom 802.11b/g WLAN [103c:12f4]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
--
02:03.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:006b]
    Kernel driver in use: 8139too
```