# Need firmware for my Broadcom 43xx wireless adapter

Tags: networking, firmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get the Broadcom BCM4306 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44659/how-do-you-get-the-broadcom-bcm4306-wireless-card-working)
>   [Firmware missing for Broadcom 802.11b/g Adapter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88854/firmware-missing-for-broadcom-802-11b-g-adapter)

Where do I get a wireless firmware (bcm43xx_microcode*.fm) for my wireless device?

Answer (score 0):

Installing the firmware-b43-installer package should provide the necessary firmwares.

```
apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```