# How to install a Broadcom BCM4306 Wireless on MacBook Air

Tags: wireless, broadcom, macbook-air

I installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my MacBook Air and I am not able to connect to the wifi.

I executed the to following command:

```
jb@jb-MacBookAir:~$ nmcli dev
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --         
jb@jb-MacBookAir:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:b0600000-b0607fff memory:b0400000-b05fffff
```

jb@jb-MacBookAir:~$

So as explained in "[How do you get the Broadcom BCM4306 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44659/how-do-you-get-the-broadcom-bcm4306-wireless-card-working)" I installed "b43-fwcutter" and "firmware-b43-installer" by following the following procedure:

"Téléchargez le pilote ici et sauvegardez-le sur un support externe,
Copiez l'archive dans votre dossier personnel,
Puis dans le dossier /lib/firmware/ avec la commande suivante que vous entrez dans un terminal:
sudo cp broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2 /lib/firmware/
Déplacez-vous dans le dossier /lib/firmware/ :
cd /lib/firmware
Décompressez-y votre archive avec les droits d'administration:
sudo tar xfvj broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
Nettoyer votre dossier:
sudo rm *.bz2
Redémarrez votre ordinateur."

Unfortunatly it didn't work. It is still saying 'No Wi-Fi Adapter Found".

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem ?

Thank you so much!

Jeremy

Comment: Which card, a BCM4306 or a BCM 4360?  You refer to both.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I don't understand why do you ask me to edit the question ? Does something is missing ? thanks

Comment: it is the BCM4360

Comment: jb@jb-MacBookAir:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0117]
 Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
 Kernel modules: bcma
04:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SS9183 PCIe SSD Controller [1b4b:9183] (rev 14)
jb@jb-MacBookAir:~$


jb@jb-MacBookAir:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
jb@jb-MacBookAir:~$

Answer (score 0):

For your MBA, you need to install 'broadcom-sta-source' and 'broadcom-sta-dkms'. Remove all b43-* drivers you might have installed as they conflict with your card's drivers (if I remember correctly).

```
sudo apt install broadcom-sta-source broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Comment: There is no need to remove `b43` firmware. There is no harm in it. And there is no need to install two packages. The correct one is `bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: jb@jb-MacBookAir:~$ sudo apt-get install '/media/jb/LINUX/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb' ources: irq:18 memory:b0600000-b0607fff memory:b0400000-b05fffff
[sudo] password for jb:
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for jb:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'bcmwl-kernel-source' instead of '/media/jb/LINUX/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb'

Comment: E: Unable to locate package ources:
E: Unable to locate package irq:18
E: Unable to locate package memory:b0600000-b0607fff
E: Unable to locate package memory:b0400000-b05fffff

Comment: Don't you have internet at all on this machine currently? I mean no ethernet (via thunderbolt-rj45 adapter)? If so and you are trying to install offline, then get 'dkms' package as it is a dependency. Then do, `sudo dpkg -i dkms_<version for 19.10>.deb` and then, `sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb`.

Comment: In deed I have no internet connection at all. I executed cmd above but something didn't went well : jb@jb-MacBookAir:~/Documents/Driver$ sudo dpkg -i dkms_2.7.1-4ubuntu2.1_all.deb
 [sudo] password for jb:
(Reading database ... 144873 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack dkms_2.7.1-4ubuntu2.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.7.1-4ubuntu2.1) over (2.7.1-4ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up dkms (2.7.1-4ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.7-3) ...
jb@jb-MacBookAir:~/Documents/

Comment: jb@jb-MacBookAir:~/Documents$ sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 144873 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 5.3.0-18-generic

Comment: Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.3.0-18-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.3.0-18-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.0-18-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--install):
 installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
jb@jb-MacBookAir:~/Documents$

Comment: It means you have to download the kernel headers package as well and install it with dpkg command (`dpkg -i linux-headers-<your_version>.deb`). But then it may have other dependencies. It's better if you can get hold of an adapter (borrow if possible) or buy a wireless adapter that has linux support. I've a MacBookAir 11" and faced same issue as you. That is the reason I'm trying to answer even though the question has been 'closed' by others. In my case, I purchased thunderbolt-to-RJ45 dongle. Once, the driver was installed, the wireless works fine.