# how do I get a Broadcom bcm 4311 working?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-not-working)

I have an HP nx6310 equipped with wifi card broadcom bcm 4311. It was perfectly working on ubuntu 11.04 with STA driver, then i made a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 and it stops working.

After trying lot of solutions the only working for me has been the one found in [this site](http://nfolamp.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/ubuntu-11-10-getting-wireless-bcm4311-working/). So I put the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo reboot
```

And now wifi is working!