# Wireless connection doesn't work on a BCM4311

Tags: 11.10, wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-not-working)

I upgrade to 11.10 and I can no longer connect.  I'm very much a newbie when it comes to linux, so any explanation would be much appreciated.

After upgrading to 11.10, the startup screen started saying "waiting for network configuration" and after a minute or so it would then say "booting without network configuration".

I have a dell vostro 1000 (not sure the year)

After typing

```
sudo rfkill list
```

I get

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: yes
      Hard blocked: yes
```

any suggestions?

and

```
 sudo rfkill unblock all
```

doesn't change anything.

The Network controller is BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
and the Ethernet controller is a BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX

I now believe that the problem with my wired connection is a faulty Ethernet cable or physical hardware that connects to the Ethernet cable as I got the wired connection to work but is sensitive to being physically touched,  I which case I would still like to get the wireless working

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable the wireless driver.

1. go to "System Settings" -> Additional Drivers"
2. Ensure that "Broadcom STA Wireless driver" is enabled
3. reboot if needed

You shouldn't generally need to manually run commands like dhclient connect, since the NetworkManager process should be taking care of things like that.

Comment: it says "activated and currently used."