# Wireless doesn't work after installing 11.10

Tags: 11.10, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-not-working)

I just did a fresh install of 11.10 32 bit and I can't get my wireless to work. I installed the drivers the Broadcom STA wireless drivers through additional drivers and rebooted, but it still doesn't see any wireless networks[image]

Did something change in 11.10 that makes the wireless card not work anymore? I was using 10.10 before, and it worked fine.

Do I need to go back to 10.10?

```
sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for user1: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 00:1f:16:be:55:ff
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.119 duplex=full firmware=sb v2.19 ip=192.168.0.70 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 memory:f0300000-f030ffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0400000-f0403fff
```

Comment: could you update your post with this information `lshw -C network` ???

Comment: try this KiLLeRfriend's post -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-not-working and that's all

Comment: Thanks, this command from that post worked:    Removed the Broadcom STA wireless Driver from Additional Drivers.
    type bcm in Ubuntu software center,
    Install "Installer Package for firmware for the b34 driver" (firmware-b43-installer)