# Firmware missing .can't connect to the internet ? please help

Tags: 11.10, mac, firmware

am using a macbook air (late 2008) dual-booted mac osx and ubuntu 11.10 
i cant connect to the internet as it says firmware missing 
i did the "dmesg | grep -i firm" command and this was the result :-

```
[    0.209432] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored <br>
[    2.377469] Broadcom 43xx driver loaded [ Features: PNL, Firmware-ID: FW13 ] <br>
[    2.598274] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/n0initvals11.fw" not found <br> 
[    2.598278] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode11.fw" not found <br>
[    2.598282] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
```

What to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the internet with a cable, open the `Additional Drivers` tool from your dash, the driver for your wireless card should be there and you just need to install it.

If by some reason that driver does not work open `Additional Drivers` tool again, remove the driver and open the Ubuntu Software Center, look for **bmc** in the search box and install the package.

Don't forget to reboot just in case the new modules are not being loaded.