# Wireless Card MAC not showing up

Tags: wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working)

I installed ubuntu 10.11 on a Dell Inspiron E1505. The Broadcom driver is active, but the Wireless card isn't being detected. There is no MAC address in the Wireless Network Configuration. Ifconfig only shows the Wired NIC. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I meant ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working

Answer (score 0):

From [nfolamp blog](http://nfolamp.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/ubuntu-11-10-getting-wireless-bcm4311-working/):

> I have an HP laptop model nx6325 with a Broadcom BCM4311 wireless
>   card.  After installing Ubuntu 11.10, I find that my wireless doesn’t
>   work.  The reason, Ubuntu detects the wireless but then loads the
>   incorrect driver for this card.
>
> I use the lspci command to display the details about my hardware. It
>   will display all of your PCI connected hardware. I edited the output
>   to show only the relevant information.  The important information here
>   for  matching your hardware with mine is this indentifier [14e4:4312].
>
> ```
> $ sudo lspci -v   
> 30:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation
> BCM4311 802.11a/b/g (rev 01)
>       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Broadcom 802.11a/b/g WLAN
>      Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
>      Memory at c8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
>      Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 2
>      Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
>      Capabilities: [d0] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
>      Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
>      Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
>      Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
>      Kernel modules: ssb   
>
> $ sudo lspci -nn 
> 30:00.0 Network controller [0280]:  Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11a/b/g
> [14e4:4312] (rev 01)
> ```
>
> **The Solution**
>
> I am  going to install the correct driver for this wireless card. Then
>   I will remove the “incorrect” driver (bcmwl) which Ubuntu installed by
>   default.
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get update
> $ sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
> $ sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
> $ sudo reboot
> ```
>
> Hopefully you found this useful.
>
> If you have this same type of wireless chip in your laptop, these
>   instructions might also work for you.