# Wireless problem. I have looked through the tutorial!

Tags: 11.10, wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working)

I have just downloaded my first Ubuntu version which is 11.10.

I now cant access my wireless. I have looked through the tutorial but it said I should see claimed, unclaimed, enabled or disabled! None of that is there as you can see. I have downloaded ndiswrapper! Could someone point me in the right direction of how to solve this? Thanks!

This is `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network
description: Network controller product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN 
vendor: Broadcom Corporation physical id: 0 bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
version: 01 width: 32 bits 
clock: 33MHz 
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list 
configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0 
resources: irq:17 memory:fe8fc000-fe8fffff *-network 
description: Ethernet interface 
product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX 
vendor: Broadcom Corporation 
physical id: 0 
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0 
logical name: eth1 
version: 02 
serial: 00:19:b9:7e:4b:c0 
size: 10Mbit/s 
capacity: 100Mbit/s 
width: 32 bits 
clock: 33MHz 
capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation 
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=b44 driverversion=2.0 duplex=half latency=64 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
resources: irq:21 
memory:fe5fe000-fe5fffff
```

Comment: check out the community documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx