# How do I enable wireless on a Macbook Pro 5,2 (17-inch from mid-2009)?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, broadcom, macbook, apple

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 on my Ubuntu partition on my macbook pro and I love it.  Except I have no wireless option/icon to select a wireless network.

I have done some digging online to see what I need to do to get the AirPort wireless to work as I had to do this once before on a older version of Ubuntu.

Currently I am unable to find anything on how to get this to work, was wondering if someone has experienced the same issue or if someone with more knowledge on this subject matter could help?

Interfaces:
en1:
  Card Type:    AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0x8D)
  Firmware Version: Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.100.98.75.18)

Comment: Built-in AirPort Extreme Wi-Fi wireless networking2 (based on IEEE 802.11n draft specification); IEEE 802.11a/b/g compatible

Comment: I have added the information above, it is Broadcom

Comment: Thanks alot!!!  That worked perfectly, except I didn't have to do the last step after rebooting.

Comment: Didnt have to do this step:  After I did the above the wireless had to be unblocked by rfkill

Answer (score 1):

Steps I took for fixing this problem, follow these steps:

- [How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working)
- After I did the above the wireless had to be unblocked by rfkill:

  ```
  rfkill unblock all
  ```