# No wireless connection detected HP Pavilion DV6 1220 with a Broadcom BCM 4312

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my HP Pavilion DV6 1220 ek and the Laptop doesn't detect any wireless connection. Two hours before that, Windows 7 was running on my machine and the WiFi functioned perfectly.

Does anyone have an idea? I've been trying for several hours to fix it without success.

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1508]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
--
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:3628]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Output of `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up;iwconfig`:

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such file or directory
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

Comment: Does Ubuntu detect any wireless networks? Is there an option for wireless in network manager or does it say "Wireless Disabled by Hardware Switch?"

Comment: Please open a terminal and type `lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2`, copy the output and add it to the question.

Comment: Also, post the output of sudo ifconfig wlan0 up;iwconfig;

Comment: @William: The Wifi is switched on but nothing shows me if there is Some network available in my Area. I'm now on my other Computer and there is more than 15 Wifi networks available.

Comment: What about the output of `rfkill list`

Comment: Does the wireless worked fine on live CD/DVD or live USB?
If it was working fine with either of these then you can go manually install the driver by inserting DVD/USB.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=194&p=497599#p497599
It is an approved method among various users: http://forum.ubuntu-tr.net/index.php?topic=30521.0

Or while using wired connection, you can use

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Or you can try: [How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working)

Comment: Your chip runs fine with the b43 driver (installed by default) when it has the firmware from the firmware-b43-lpphy-installer.  Forget the bcmwl... packages.  Not sure what version of the firmware the linux-firmare-nonfree installs, but since the names are so similar to the non-lpphy firmware, that package may not work for you.