# Wireless doesn't work for me in Lubuntu but does in Puppy?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, lubuntu

I am new to GNU Linux. I have been having trouble getting wireless working on my installed system of Lubuntu 11.10. It sees my WPA network but cannot connect even when I remove the password.

Looking around for a different distro that might replace it, I was amazed to find that Puppy was able to connect to my wireless network without trouble, running off a USB stick. So this makes me think that my Lubuntu wireless problem might be fixable so I don't have to have the major hassle of backing up all my documents etc before installing a different distro to the laptop. Can anyone suggest some steps that might help me to fix wireless on Lubuntu, perhaps using the fact it works with Puppy? Thanks.

Rob

**EDIT:** *(Thank you both for the advice and link on making the question more useful. Hope this is better...)*

(PS. WEP doesn't work either; rebooting doesn't help)

Here is the output for Lubuntu (wireless network on; wired ethernet connection to laptop unplugged):

**> lspci -nn**
    ...
    10:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 02)

**> ifconfig**
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:c4:c9:80:75
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:22 Memory:e4600000-e4620000

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1a:73:e6:b6:16
          inet6 addr: fe80::21a:73ff:fee6:b616/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:31840 (31.8 KB)  TX bytes:31840 (31.8 KB)

***Btw, on Puppy,*** ifconfig ***gives:***
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:120 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:120 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:9104 (8.8 KiB)  TX bytes:9104 (8.8 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1A:73:E6:B6:16
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17375 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16352 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:17577062 (16.7 MiB)  TX bytes:3587630 (3.4 MiB)

*(Back to Lubuntu:)*
**> sudo lshw -class network**
[sudo] password:
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82562GT 10/100 Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:1c:c4:c9:80:75
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e   driverversion=1.3.10-k2 firmware=1.1-2 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:43 memory:e4600000-e461ffff memory:e4620000-e4620fff   ioport:4020(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:10:00.0
       logical name: eth2
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1a:73:e6:b6:16
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=5.100.82.38 latency=0   multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
       resources: irq:17 memory:e4000000-e4003fff

**> rfkill list all**
0: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

*The output from*
    **dmesg

    dmesg | grep -i firmware

    cat /var/log/udev

    cat /var/log/dmesg

    cat /var/log/Xorg.0

   ls -lrt /var/log**
*is [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/932113/) if required! (pardon my ignorance)*

## Further (more than a month later):

Well, finally I tried the suggestions on that page suggested by fossfreedom, and pages linked therein (did things one at a time with reboots where suggested):

did the suggested uninstalls (bcmwl-kernel-source package),
did the installs (firmware-b43-installer and b43-fwcutter packages),
commented out the blacklist (in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf)

etc, etc, and variations suggested.

### Wireless still doesn't work.

Out of interest, here's what I get with the following. Is the "access denied"
significant/suggestive? Does anyone kind, lucid and patient, have any other ideas?

```
> lspci -vnn -d 14e4:
```

10:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN

[14e4:4311] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4311 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller

[103c:1375]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at e4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: ssb

Also,

> modprobe -r wl
>   FATAL: Module wl not found.

Another point: in Additional Drivers, the proprietary driver is still shown but is not active. Couldn't see how to remove it (only inactivate it). Neither worked (active or inactive).

My PC-ID of [14e4:4311] is supported according to this page:
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43

I don't grok at all what's going on. Not even the basics. Did at one point but am so befuddled now that I need a holiday. It's clear this distro was a bad choice for my level of non-expertise (will inform the friend who suggested it but uses something else; feel like a guinea pig).

Comment: I understand that your driver seems to be properly connected, but it would be helpful to know what your wireless adapter is. Please copy your wireless adapter from `lspci` (or `lsusb` if it's a USB wireless adapter). Also your output from `ifconfig`. I guess rebooting doesn't solve the issue? What if you disable WPA, is it able to connect?

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Please can you see if any of the answers here help with your issue - http://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working

Comment: Still not had the chance to try these out. Will do this weekend. Thanks, fossfreedom...

Comment: Tried them out today. Still stuck!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)