# Wireless available but not being used with a BCM4311

Tags: 12.04, broadcom

I'm re-purposing a Gateway 6703.  After [following](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working) advice, the Broadcom hardware shows up in `ifconfig`, and `rfkill` shows no blocking.  The problem is, even though wifi is enabled, the no wireless scan or connection is made.  Any ideas why that might be?  Can I force the wireless to connect?  Is there an app I should be running?  Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

Go to software center, type "bcm" then search, and it is the b43 broadcom driver, or something like that, install (I uninstalled and reinstalled the other ones, and installed the b43 one): [How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working) ...

After an entire day, I am wireless again.