# Wireless doesn't work on an Acer TravelMate 5520G with a Broadcom 4311

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

I have already install a clean Ubuntu 12.04 in an Acer. After the installation, the wifi was not detected. I have followed several bcm431X tutorials (from this forum), but no-one worked out.

In summary, I have tried installing b43-fwcutter & firmware-b43-installer packages, and also, in first instance, bcmwl-kernel-source.

Here is the lspci output.

```
05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AMBIT Microsystem Corp. Device 0422
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at f0400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: ssb
```

What can I do to solve the problem?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: See here → http://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working

Comment: Already tried both solutions, but it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem and I think I solved it. I had Travelmate 5520G with Vista and Ubuntu 10.10 installed and with wlan working good. Then I replaced the 10.10 with 12.04 so the problems started. I installed b43-fwcutter and stuff but the problem persisted.

The problem solved by shutting down the SLA-driver that was on by default in Ubuntu and rebooting the laptop to Vista. When running Vista, the wlan led was **on** and blinked once in a while. I pulled the wlan switch so the wlan connection and the led turned **off**. Next I rebooted the laptop. And now, against all predictions, wlan worked on Ubuntu 12.04. I am not 100% sure if shutting down the SLA-driver had any effect to the result but that is what I did before rebooting to Vista.

We are living in a mysterious world, fellas.