# Not getting wireless icon , not even wifi visible , wireless button is on

Tags: 12.04, wireless

i am using compaq presario v 3000 tu   laptop .

today i have installed 12.04 ubuntu  . but very sad i was not able to  connect through wifi . for me it's useless without wifi .  tried lot of command posted on net  but unable to rectify the problem  ---

while running Runtil wlan manager i am getting this error --

****Critical error :
Can't find any wireless network interface.
Code : -3****

plz  help  ..

following is output of command run by me on my system ..

**ifconfig----**-------------------------

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:d3:9b:11:52  
          inet addr:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:d3ff:fe9b:1152/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4345 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3896 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4648555 (4.6 MB)  TX bytes:552728 (552.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:380 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:380 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:33143 (33.1 KB)  TX bytes:33143 (33.1 KB)
```

**lspci** ------------------------

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
08:08.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation PRO/100 VE Network Connection (rev 02)
08:09.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller
08:09.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 19)
08:09.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 0a)
08:09.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 05)
```

**rfkill list all** -------------------------------------

```
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**dmesg** -------------------------------------

```
[    0.000000] MTRR variable ranges enabled:
[    0.000000]   0 base 000000000 mask FE0000000 write-back
[    0.000000]   1 base 01F700000 mask FFFF00000 uncachable
[    0.000000]   2 base 01F800000 mask FFF800000 uncachable
[    0.000000]   3 disabled
[    0.000000]   4 disabled
[    0.000000]   5 disabled
[    0.000000]   6 disabled
[    0.000000]   7 disabled
[    0.000000] PAT not supported by CPU.
[    0.000000] original variable MTRRs
[    0.000000] reg 0, base: 0GB, range: 512MB, type WB
[    0.000000] reg 1, base: 503MB, range: 1MB, type UC
[    0.000000] reg 2, base: 504MB, range: 8MB, type UC
[    0.000000] total RAM covered: 503M
[    0.000000] Found optimal setting for mtrr clean up
[    0.000000]  gran_size: 64K  chunk_size: 16M         num_reg: 3      lose cover RAM: 0G
[    0.000000] New variable MTRRs
[    0.000000] reg 0, base: 0GB, range: 512MB, type WB
[    0.000000] reg 1, base: 503MB, range: 1MB, type UC
[    0.000000] reg 2, base: 504MB, range: 8MB, type UC
[    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [c00f67e0] f67e0
[    0.000000] initial memory mapped : 0 - 02000000
[    0.000000] Base memory trampoline at [c009b000] 9b000 size 16384
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: 0000000000000000-000000001f680000
[    0.000000]  0000000000 - 0000200000 page 4k
[    0.000000]  0000200000 - 001f600000 page 2M
[    0.000000]  001f600000 - 001f680000 page 4k
[    0.000000] kernel direct mapping tables up to 1f680000 @ 1ffb000-2000000
[    0.000000] RAMDISK: 1d9e9000 - 1e766000
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 000f66f0 00024 (v03 HP    )
[    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 1f684f0f 00084 (v01 HPQOEM SLIC-MPC 06040000  LTP 00000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 1f68dc38 000F4 (v03 INTEL  CALISTGA 06040000 ALAN 00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 1f6864cc 076F8 (v01 HPQOEM SLIC-MPC 06040000 MSFT 03000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 1f68efc0 00040
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 1f68dd2c 00068 (v01 HPQOEM SLIC-MPC 06040000 LOHR 00000064)
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 1f68dd94 00038 (v01 HPQOEM SLIC-MPC 06040000 LOHR 00000064)
```

Comment: Your wlan is from **Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g**. Download and install latest driver may fix your problem.

Comment: Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/38700/76684) post.

Comment: flagged as a possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working

Answer (score 0):

try the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

If your card is older, you may have to try the legacy installer, which you can do by typing in the following:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer
```

Good luck!