# 12.04 LTS wireless not working in Dell Insprion E1405

Tags: wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working)

I have the windows XP media edition running on my Dell Inspiron E1405 with all the hardware working properly. Recently i wipe out the windows and installed the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using the CD and the installation process completed successfully but my wireless stopped working after.

Computer wireless indicator turned off and I can't even do the wired connection as well. It is Broadcom BCM4311 adapter. I tried to download the driver from the dell website but they don't have the Linux version of the driver if its that causing the problem. I appreciate your help that can solve my issue. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try connect other way: with android phone or LAN cable. Then go to System settings -> Additional driver. Check drivers and install what will offered.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options for getting this wireless card to work:

1. Install linux drivers for this card as documented here:

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

1. Install drivers using ndiswrapper as documented here:

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper