# Broadcom BCM4311 issues, kind of working but need help

Tags: wireless, 12.10, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working)

I have a Dell laptop and I just updated to 12.10. Once the update completed WIFI stopped working. I searched the issue and it seems to be common and I ended up installing loads of different drivers to sort the issue.

Now I am at a point where when the laptop boots it seems to pick up the wrong driver and WIFI doesn't work. But if I run the command "sudo modprobe b43" WIFI starts working.

I have used commands found at this link to blacklist other drivers and uninstalled some but I have to assume there is a driver running on boot.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Switching_between_drivers

I am more or less a noob when it comes to Ubuntu so any help resolving this issue would be great.

Thanks