# How to troubleshoot WiFi (BCM4313) problems with Lenovo G580?

Tags: 12.10, wireless, lenovo

Yes, there are lot of same problems, and I read at least 15 forum posts. But no result.
OS: 12.10

I have similar problem like this thread, so after updating to a new kernel, the wifi gone.:
[Wireless problems with Broadcom BCM4313](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232049/wireless-problems-with-broadcom-bcm4313)

but downloading and installing the .deb package, what Dimitar linked, didn't solved it. The `wl.ko` file is in the `/lib/modules/3.5.0-21-generic/updates/dkms/` folder.

Running the reinstall command, gives the following:
(`sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source` from the [offical guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx))

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  calligra-l10n-engb cdparanoia k3b k3b-data k3b-i18n kde-l10n-engb
  kde-l10n-zhcn kdevelop-l10n kdevelop-php-docs-l10n kdevelop-php-l10n
  language-pack-kde-en libasprintf0c2:i386 libcroco3:i386 libflac++6
  libgettextpo0:i386 libgomp1:i386 libk3b6 libkcddb4 libunistring0:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,181 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 202169 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace bcmwl-kernel-source 5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3 (using .../bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking replacement bcmwl-kernel-source ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3) ...
Loading new bcmwl-5.100.82.112+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.5.0-21-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.5.0-21-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-21-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
ERROR: Module b43 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module b43legacy does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module ssb does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcm43xx does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcm80211 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmfmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmsmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcma does not exist in /proc/modules
FATAL: Error inserting wl (/lib/modules/3.5.0-21-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko): Invalid argument
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-21-generic
```

More tests:

`lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0587]
```

`iwconfig`:

```
eth1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

`rfkill list all`:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
rfcomm                 42651  0 
bnep                   18140  2 
parport_pc             32688  0 
ppdev                  17073  0 
bluetooth             204950  10 rfcomm,bnep
ip6t_REJECT            12574  1 
usb_storage            48838  1 
uas                    17844  0 
xt_hl                  12521  6 
ip6t_rt                12558  3 
nf_conntrack_ipv6      14054  7 
nf_defrag_ipv6         13158  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
ipt_REJECT             12541  1 
xt_LOG                 17349  10 
xt_limit               12711  13 
xt_tcpudp              12603  18 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32007  1 
snd_hda_codec_conexant    57842  1 
xt_addrtype            12635  4 
binfmt_misc            17500  1 
xt_state               12578  14 
ip6table_filter        12815  1 
ip6_tables             27207  2 ip6t_rt,ip6table_filter
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns    12665  0 
nouveau               895609  0 
nf_conntrack_broadcast    12589  1 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns
nf_nat_ftp             12649  0 
nf_nat                 25254  1 nf_nat_ftp
nf_conntrack_ipv4      14480  9 nf_nat
nf_defrag_ipv4         12729  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_conntrack_ftp       13359  1 nf_nat_ftp
nf_conntrack           82633  8 nf_conntrack_ipv6,xt_state,nf_conntrack_netbios_ns,nf_conntrack_broadcast,nf_nat_ftp,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ftp
uvcvideo               76749  0 
iptable_filter         12810  1 
ip_tables              26995  1 iptable_filter
coretemp               13400  0 
videobuf2_core         32851  1 uvcvideo
videodev              120309  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
snd_hda_intel          33491  3 
snd_hda_codec         134212  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel
i915                  520539  3 
videobuf2_vmalloc      12860  1 uvcvideo
joydev                 17457  0 
x_tables               29711  13 ip6t_REJECT,xt_hl,ip6t_rt,ipt_REJECT,xt_LOG,xt_limit,xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,xt_state,ip6table_filter,ip6_tables,iptable_filter,ip_tables
videobuf2_memops       13368  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
ttm                    83595  1 nouveau
kvm                   414070  0 
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
rts5139               356158  0 
snd_pcm                96580  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
drm_kms_helper         49112  2 nouveau,i915
alx                    81256  0 
lib80211               14381  0 
compat                 14949  5 rfcomm,bnep,bluetooth,alx,lib80211
ghash_clmulni_intel    13180  0 
drm                   288670  6 nouveau,i915,ttm,drm_kms_helper
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30512  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61521  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29425  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
mei                    40690  0 
mxm_wmi                12979  1 nouveau
snd                    78734  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
psmouse                95552  0 
ideapad_laptop         18086  0 
wmi                    19070  2 nouveau,mxm_wmi
lpc_ich                17061  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13413  2 nouveau,i915
serio_raw              13215  0 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 ideapad_laptop
mac_hid                13205  0 
soundcore              15047  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18484  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
cryptd                 20403  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
video                  19335  2 nouveau,i915
microcode              22803  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                46345  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
```

Comment: Are there any additional clues here? sudo modprobe wl; dmesg | grep wl. By any chance did you try installing linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6? I suspect there is a conflict there and it might need to be removed.

Comment: Removing linux-backports-cw-3.6 made wifi working, but now again my LAN isnt working. I installed it , because first time I hadn't LAN, found a post, installed above package. So if I install, I have LAN-no wifi, if I remove I have Wifi-no LAN. Thats funny.

Comment: sudo modprobe wl - gives nothing. dmesg | grep wl - gives wl: module licence 'MIDEX/Proprietary' taints kernel.

Comment: Is your LAN the relatively new alx driver? I think the cw-3.6 package and the bcmwl package use different implementations of cfg80211.ko and they conflict. I am unaware of a solution.

Comment: what do you suggest? waiting for fix or any other idea?

Comment: I haven't any idea how to start. I'd enjoy my wireless and wait for a fix. Have you asked here? http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=336

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem. Using the above forum post, uninstalled linux-backports and then after reboot now I have wifi again. So the working driver is Broadcom STA, but without the backports. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12475295 Also thank you chili555 for the suggestions here and in hundreds of forum posts :)