# Getting Wireless to Work, Dell Inspiron E1505 (bcm4311)

Tags: wireless, dell, broadcom, inspiron, setup

Ok.  so I know there are about a million threads on this subject already, but NOTHING has worked for me.  About to lose my mind here, if someone can please help I will be eternally grateful.

I have a Dell Inspiron E1505 which has a Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 wireless controller.  I can't get it to work.

I've followed the steps outlined on the following sites:

[How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2072887
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper

and more. Nothing is working, and I'm on the verge of giving up.  As a Linux newbie I can only imagine I'm missing something stupidly obvious.  If someone could give me a step-by-step instruction for going from a completely fresh 12.10 install to having a working wifi connection I would be (as mentioned earlier) eternally grateful.  Please let me know if anyone needs more info.

Comment: Seems like all you need is `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter` to install the driver, and reboot. Needless to say, you'll need a wired connection for the command to work, and in case there are any errors, post them.

Comment: @mikewhatever: just did a fresh install, ran that line on terminal and got no errors.  Unplugged ethernet, rebooted -- nothing.  if I run iwconfig I get: lo no wireless extensions, eth1 no wireless extensions.  I've tried hitting the Fn+F2 key which is supposed to turn wireles on and off and it makes no difference.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Check if the b43 module is loaded: `lsmod | grep b43`. If not, load it with `sudo modprobe b43`. If you want serious help, please add the output of `lsmod` and `lspci` to the question.

Comment: Also make sure your hardware switch it in the "On" position.

Comment: Please run lspci -vvnn -d 14e4:    and confirm that the pci-id of the chip is NOT [14e4:4313]    According to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43
That chip takes the wl driver and not the b43.

Comment: @mikewhatever that did it.  I could kiss you.  Question, it looks like when I reboot I have to sudo modprobe b43 each time, how can I make it load automatically?

Comment: Yep, that's also easy. Just run `echo b43 | sudo tee -a /etc/modules`. That adds b43 to /etc/modules to autoload it. I've put all the steps into an answer below.

Comment: This answer is WORKING THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!! 3 days I am looking for a working answer and finaly a got it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a clean install, connect an ethernet cable, open a terminal window, and run

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
```

Then run `echo b43 | sudo tee -a /etc/modules` to make sure the module is autoloaded. Reboot, and if all goes well, the wireless should work.

Comment: thanks again, sir.  eternal gratitude.  Hope someone else finds this useful as well

Comment: Most welcome, glad I could help.

Comment: I would like to test this on an Ubuntu 22.04 installer run from USB stick, *before* actually overwriting my old Win7 on the hard disk. Can this be tested in any way without rebooting? Or can I make the changes permanent on the USB drive, so they survive a reboot? For 25 years I have been wondering now why Linux does not just work out of the box. I know how to use Linux incl. console, but setting up the hardware to actually work has always been a pain on all the laptops I ever tested it on.

Comment: @kriegaex Sure, test it. Wireless connectivity has improved a lot in the last 25 years. I don't have the exact hardware in question, but BCM4313 just worked in 20.04. You might get lucky too.

Comment: I would not have asked if it worked in 22.04. It does not. Even as early as GRUB I already needed an extra parameter to see anything but vertical stripes on the screen, just like back in 2008 with the exact same laptop. Nothing has improved for me, and I keep switching back to Windows. Not to mention the WiFi driver.

Comment: Oh well, what can I say. Try again in 2047. :~)