# No Network devices available on Inspiron e1505 running ubuntu 16

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, broadcom, ethernet

Trying really hard to bring an old e1505 back to life. A few days ago I installed Ubuntu 16 on it and worked fine, except it can't find any network devices. The weird thing is that it can detect the ethernet port when I boot it from the Live CD, but after installing it it couldn't find anything. However, I got it working by reinstalling the system. The Wi-Fi wasn't working, but ethernet did work. Later I managed to fix Wi-Fi with the help of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/271044/getting-wireless-to-work-dell-inspiron-e1505-bcm4311) but then I did something horribly wrong with the system and I had to reinstall again, but after this reinstall it can't find any network devices. 

Here's the output of `ifconfig`:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:804 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:804 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:59440 (59.4 KB)  TX bytes:59440 (59.4 KB)
```

and `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV515/M52 [Mobility Radeon X1300]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)
03:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller
03:01.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 19)
03:01.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 0a)
03:01.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 05)
0b:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
```

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Any help would be really appreciated. 
Googled it many times, didn't find a anything which could help 
PS I am a real noob in linux/ubuntu as I started learning to use it a few days ago so please be as clears as you can when answering. If any additional information is required comment and I will edit the question

Comment: You can get the Ethernet temporarily working by `sudo modprobe b44`. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: `sudo modprobe 44` is stuck, doesn't output anything, doesn't fix it either. edited question and added the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed a wrong wireless driver that also blacklisted the Ethernet adapter. You can fix it this way.

Run

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot.

After that the Ethernet adapter should work. Connect to the internet by wire and install firmware for your wireless adapter by

```
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: is it normal for `sudo modprobe b44` to not output anything and get stuck  for a really long time?

Comment: It should output nothing if it is ok. If Ethernet does not work after the first two commands, then reboot.

Comment: well it does output nothing but its stuck and does not finish.

Comment: So press Ctrl+C, then reboot.

Comment: rebooting now. askubuntu needs 1 more character so here is a full sentence.

Comment: yeah and BTW it is stuck at shutting down so i have to hold the power button. hope that doesn't break anything, right? gonna fix that next

Comment: Ethernet fixed, now fixing wifi. Thx

Comment: OMG you fixed everything yaay thank u so much wiiiiii.