# Wireless Very slow with 13.10 and BCM4313

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.10, broadcom

I have a laptop with the BCM4313, and it was working perfectly in Ubuntu 13.04, but I recently upgraded to 13.10 and now my wireless performance is horrible.

Initially it didn't work at all, but I removed the wl driver and use the brcmsmac driver instead. Now when I boot up it works at the start, but gets progressively slower.

My Android device is reporting 10Mbps down/20Mbps up, but my laptop only gets 1up/down.

Does anyone know a solution?  I really need my wireless to work, is my best option to just reinstall on 13.04?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working)

Comment: I have the same problem in my Samsung QX510. Was trying few drivers, but they were working only after insallation (I've added rest to black list, but didn't work), or only in part of times were working good...

Comment: @Kaobear, no it's not a duplicate of that I have my drivers installed, it's just slow, and it's a problem that's new in 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the kernel are you using? if 3.10 try a do-release-upgrade (even if you are on 13.10) you should get 3.11 next.

I installed from ISO and had the same problem, but when doing a do-release-upgrade after the install i was given a later kernel. This addressed my issues.

Comment: I am on 3.11, this does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing wicd??Seems to help other people.

Enter following commands in terminal

1. `sudo apt-get install wicd`         Follow through installation
2. Reboot
3. `sudo rm /var/lib/wicd/resolv.conf.orig`
4. `sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /var/lib/wicd/resolv.conf.orig`
5. `sudo service network-manager stop`
6. Connect using wicd

   ### Remove Network Manager
7. `sudo apt-get purge network-manager`
8. Reboot and you should be using Wicd and see better speeds!!