# Dell Inspiron 1525, Upgraded to 12.04 and have lost Wireless Internet Connection

Tags: wireless, drivers, 12.04, dell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4312](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312)

I've just upgraded my Dell Inspiron 1525 to 12.04.  Wireless connection worked before, but now it doesn't.  I can't seem to start the driver.  I remember having to activate it manually for the last version and it worked fine but it doesn't with this new 12.04 upgrade.

When I go to "Additional Drivers", I am shown one option named "Broadcom STA wireless driver".  When I try to activate it, I get this message:

> Sorry, installation of this driver failed.  Please have a look at the
> log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log

The message entered into the log is:

> 2012-04-26 22:17:36,194 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
> 2012-04-26 22:17:36,491 WARNING: modinfo for module wl failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module wl
>
> 2012-04-26 22:17:36,492 WARNING: /sys/module/wl/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind wl driver
> 2012-04-26 22:17:36,556 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Comment: is your notebook 64 bit?

Comment: 32-bit.  I tried that but it said that I already had the most up-to-date driver.  Instead, I removed it using "sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source" and then installed it again, through the "Additional Drivers" gui.  Not sure why, but it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain further how you got it working. I ran into the same problem. I tried what you said but still could not get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

@rdeth use
*sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source* command to remove and then install again using additional drivers interface it worked like that for me

Comment: +1 I have exactly this machine and had exactly this problem. Removing bcmwl-kernel-source and then reinstalling through Additional Drivers worked to restore wireless on my Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n.