# Wireless problems with Inspiron 1545 in version 12.04

Tags: wireless, dell, inspiron

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I can't seem to locate an answer on how to install the wireless drivers for it. I'm a noob linux user so, complete directions are appreciated. If you need anything to help solve the problem, you need only ask and I shall provide. Thank you, in advance, to anyone who offers any help for me.

Answer (score 5):

Plug in the ethernet cable

run these commands in terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Then unplug ethernet and reboot

Answer (score 1):

This will show how to install the wireless driver: [Dell Inspiron 1525, Upgraded to 12.04 and have lost Wireless Internet Connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125624/dell-inspiron-1525-upgraded-to-12-04-and-have-lost-wireless-internet-connection)

This will show how to unlock the hardware switch: [Dell Inspiron 1525, Upgraded to 12.04 and have lost Wireless Internet Connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125624/dell-inspiron-1525-upgraded-to-12-04-and-have-lost-wireless-internet-connection)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the terminal. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open up the terminal. Then type this exactly like this:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

Comment: Nothing appeared to happen and I still don't have wireless.

Comment: Used the solution from this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125624/dell-inspiron-1525-upgraded-to-12-04-and-have-lost-wireless-internet-connection

However, now it says disabled by hardware switch. I pressed my switch and there was no response.

Comment: And here is the solution for that little issue. I recomend listing all the devices before unblocking them. http://askubuntu.com/questions/139036/ubuntu-12-04-says-wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch

Answer (score 0):

1.Open *System settings*  and click on *Network*.

2.Then click *Wireless* and turn it on.

3.Click on the network name drop down and choose *Other*.

4.Give the network you want to connect. For example `TP-LINK_AAB61C`.

5.Select the *Wireless security* and provide the password. Then click *Connect*.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for the Dell Inspirion 1545 with 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

along with opening this file to fix no sound issue:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

then add this to the end of the file once opened ..

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

save, close and reboot.