# how can I connect to internet using wifi on my Dell Inspiron 1545 running on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Inspiron 1545 and I can successfully connect to the Internet using an Ethernet cable but not when I try and connect through the wifi.

Any help would be appreciated.

My Wireless Card Details:-

Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: Check this
http://askubuntu.com/questions/141834/wireless-problems-with-inspiron-1545-in-version-12-04

Answer (score 0):

Please obtain a working ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

After it completes, detach the ethernet and do:

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

Your wireless should be working. In a few cases, it takes a reboot.