# Wireless is not getting connected on starting 12.04

Tags: wireless, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4312](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312)

I am new to Ubuntu. I have just upgraded to 12.04 and the wireless is not working. I am sending you the results of the following codes, in case it helps.

Code:

```
iwconfig
rfkill list all
```

Result

```
omega@debasmita-laptop:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth2      IEEE 802.11  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Link Quality:5  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0

eth1      no wireless extensions.

omega@debasmita-laptop:~$ rfkill list all
0: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
```