# Broadcom Wireless not working after upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless

I've upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and my wireless isn't working anymore.

Here is some information about the system:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | grep bcm
# Warning: This file is autogenerated by bcmwl. All changes to this file will be lost.
blacklist bcm43xx

blacklist bcma
#blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist bcm43xx

$ sudo gedit blacklist.conf

[sudo] password for alexandre: 

$ rfkill list all

0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN

    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

$ rfkill unblock 0

$ rfkill list all

0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$  lspci -nn | grep 0280

06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
```

Computer Acer Aspire 5315.
Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: Every time the computers reboots I have this:


alexandre:$ rfkill list all
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Anything new about this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4312](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312)

Comment: Closed as too-localised since the OP has not revisited this question since posting.