# Ubuntu 12.04 Broadcom wireless not working after b43

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4312](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312)

I have a Dell laptop. I was running Ubuntu 11.10 32 bit. During that time wireless was working fine. Yesterday I updated my os to 12.04.now wireless is not working.

I have tried installing b43 installer and b43 cutter from software center and activate Broadcom driver. It did not work.

Whenever I try to activate the driver, I get error saying installation failed look at `/var/log/jockey.log`

I have opened jockey log and here is the log:

```
2012-05-10 15:20:00,182 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2012-05-10 15:20:00,191 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2012-05-10 15:20:00,205 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2012-05-10 15:20:01,666 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2012-05-10 15:20:05,370 WARNING: modinfo for module wl failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module wl
2012-05-10 15:20:05,372 WARNING: /sys/module/wl/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind wl driver
2012-05-10 15:20:05,424 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted*
```

Is there anything I could do to get wireless working on my laptop?  I do not want to go back to Windows 7.

Should I have to do a fresh installation of 12.04?