# Unable to connect to wireless network on Dell Inspiron 1525

Tags: wireless, networking, inspiron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4312](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312)

I have been using Ubuntu since 9.04 and am upgrading with every new version release. Recently I have upgraded my laptop Dell inspiron 1525 from 11.10 to 12.04. At the time of upgrade there were some problems  which got cleared after trying upgrade for 3 to 4 times. Before my first upgrade, i.e. in 11.04 I was able to connect to my wireless network. After the upgrade I am unable to see the Wireless network option enabled in the networks shortcut on menu bar. Please help me to overcome this problem.

PS: I am **able** to use the wired network.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to see if you need to install proprietary drivers for your wireless card in the additional drivers menu?

Open the dash, type '*additional*' and see if your wireless card is listed there. If it is, make sure the driver is activated and relog/reboot.

Comment: Yes I see my wireless card in the additional drivers and it is activated. Tried rebooting so many times, yet wireless network option is disabled.

Comment: Any special key combo on your keyboard, like Fn+F11 or something alike that activates/deactivate wireless? I happened to me once with bluetooth