# Wireless isn't working in 12.04

Tags: wireless, broadcom, hp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4312](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312)

I'm new to Ubuntu and not very tech savvy. I have tried everything I've seen on previous posts but still I'm confused. So I know a lot of people request certain info. So here's what I have:

HP Pavilion dv5000. Only Ubuntu 12.04 running.

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS480 Host Bridge (rev 01)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS480 PCI Bridge
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS480 PCI Bridge
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 USB Host Controller
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 USB Host Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 USB2 Host Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 SMBus Controller (rev 11)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 IDE Controller
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 PCI-ISA Bridge
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 PCI-PCI Bridge
00:14.5 Multimedia audio controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:14.6 Modem: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI IXP SB400 AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 02)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Radeon XPRESS 200M 5955 (PCIE)
06:02.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02)
06:06.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
```

Comment: Try the answers in this link:- http://askubuntu.com/a/126798/25798

Answer (score 0):

Please hook up the ethernet temporarily and do:

```
    sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
    sudo modprobe -r b43
    sudo modprobe b43
```

You should be all set

Comment: sade@sade-Pavilion-dv5000-EP416UA-ABA:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
06:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)
sade@sade-Pavilion-dv5000-EP416UA-ABA:~$ rfkill list all 
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: ade@sade-Pavilion-dv5000-EP416UA-ABA:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
[sudo] password for sade: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-firmware-nonfree
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,947 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,962 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/multiverse linux-firmware-nonfree all 1.11ubuntu1 [3,947 kB]
Fetched 3,947 kB in 1s (2,347 kB/s)

Comment: Selecting previously unselected package linux-firmware-nonfree.
(Reading database ... 162051 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-firmware-nonfree (from .../linux-firmware-nonfree_1.11ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Setting up linux-firmware-nonfree (1.11ubuntu1) ...
sade@sade-Pavilion-dv5000-EP416UA-ABA:~$ sudo modprobe -r b43

Comment: sade@sade-Pavilion-dv5000-EP416UA-ABA:~$ sudo modprobe b43

Comment: OHH WAIT IT DID WORK...LOL I NEVER TOOK OUT THE ETHERNET CORD.....THANKS YOUR THE BEST