# HP Pavilion zv6000 Ubuntu kernel crash

Tags: 12.04, wireless

Ubuntu dumps the call stack/crashes. Steps I've taken.

1. I tried installing from a disc image, the install never made it past the option to "install along side Windows XP" - it dumped the callstack before actually installing. I tried 3 different CD image burns, just to make sure the ISO wasn't corrupt.
2. I then "successfully" installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 using the windows installer.
3. No wireless availability, and no wireless driver was listed as being "missing" in the "install drivers" list. I tried using the terminal to apt-get and install the correct BCM4318 driver (for the Broadcom wireless BCM3418 rev 02 on this machine), but it kernel dumped. I had to uninstall/reinstall Ubuntu completely to prevent Ubuntu from just dumping after any reboot attempt.
4. "Successfully" uninstalled then reinstalled Ubuntu using the windows installer. This time, the wireless STA driver listed under the "install drivers". However, 3/4 through installation, another kernel dump. Rebooted, Ubuntu kernel dumps after being loaded for approximately 2-3 minutes.

I suspect the wireless driver being incorrect/missing/etc, along with possibly other kernel package problems, are behind this constant kernel dumping. I have tried booting into recovery and running the "fix broken packages" option, but that also resulted in a kernel dump.

Help?!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Broadcom STA driver is incorrect for your device. I suggest you remove it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

With a temporary wired ethernet connection, then do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet cable and reboot.

Reference: [Wireless isn't working in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171427/wireless-isnt-working-in-12-04)