# sudo modprobe b43 not working in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, wireless, 13.04, drivers, modprobe

Trying to get my wireless to work in Ubuntu 13.04 to no avail.  Following the instructions in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171427/wireless-isnt-working-in-12-04), when I get to the `sudo modprobe b43` I add the `-v` to try and see what happens and it seems like it just hangs indefinitely after saying:

i`nsmod /lib/modules/3.8.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko`

Any ideas on what is happening and how I might fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal command: lspci -nn -d 14e4:

Comment: 04:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)

Answer (score 1):

I believe b43, ssb and firmware are correct for your device 14e4:4318. I wonder if the wrong driver was installed and not removed or at least removed incompletely. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Let's be sure there are no blacklists:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Look for any lines about b43 or ssb; if there are any, remove them. Proofread, save and close gedit. Reboot and if your wireless is not working as expected, post:

```
dmesg | grep -e b43 -e wlan
```

Answer (score 0):

This (SOLVED) thread on Ubuntu deals with your problem and explains how to get it working. You might want to read it carefully.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2077104

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.