# Wireless driver for dell inspiron 5520

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4312](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312)

I have a new Dell Inspiron 15R 5520 laptop running Ubuntu 12.04. My wireless driver doesn't get detected in the Additional Drivers.  Please help. `Hardware: 14E4:4365`

Comment: ^^^ try this and edit your question if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/a/175115/83159

The same wireless hardware, but another model and Ubuntu version (oneiric). It doesn't work on my Inspiron like yours, but I think I do something wrong. Try it.

Comment: I have tried all the listed suggestions, but whatever I do, The driver never sows up in "Additional Drivers"

Comment: Have you tried Ndiswrapper?

Comment: No, i haven't tried ndiswrapper