# wireless is disabled by hardware lenovo 3000g430

Tags: wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4312](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312)

sir i have problem with my wifi switch

sir please tell me solution for my problem (wifi is disabled by hardware).

***output of sudo lshw -C network is***

```
   sudo] password for sudheer: 
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: eth2
       version: 01
       serial: 00:21:00:72:3a:93
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=5.100.82.38 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
       resources: irq:19 memory:f4700000-f4703fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1e:68:ad:24:0b
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.121 duplex=full firmware=sb v3.04 ip=172.16.52.79 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 memory:f4600000-f460ffff
```

***output of  iwconfig is***

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth2      IEEE 802.11  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Link Quality:5  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.

sudheer@sudheer:~$ sudo iwlistscanning
sudo: iwlistscanning: command not found
***sudheer@sudheer:~$ sudo iwlist scanning***
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth2      Failed to read scan data : Invalid argument

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

Comment: The answer from the following link should fix your wifi.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312

Answer (score 0):

Try with command.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
rfkill unblock all
```