# No Wireless LAN HP Pavillion dv6000

Tags: wireless, lan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working)

the physical switch is in the on position but the indicator light is red meaning its not on. when i boot into windows vista it works normal. i do not see any networks nor can i connect to anything. wired Internet works.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/168055/wireless-does-not-work-on-hp-dv6000-with-a-bcm4311 or http://askubuntu.com/questions/203902/no-wireless-lan-hp-pavillion-dv6000 or http://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312 but most of all: [How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/how-can-i-get-broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-working)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed additional drivers for wifi?
If not, get a temporary wired internet connection and install it.
you can install it by searching *additional drivers* in unity or by using `gksu jockey-gtk` command.

Press the start button on your keyboard and type *additional drivers*, select the additional drivers application, you'll get a window like the one shown below. install your wifi driver in there.

[image: Aditional Drivers in unity]

[image: Additional Drivers]

Comment: honestly im a noob to ubuntu. can you write that out step by step for me please if its not a big bother to you?  i have no clue what unity is.

Comment: umm. i can not seem to find the additional drivers app when i search it....

Comment: Try to follow this video,
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUp9pSqK61U
it might help