# How do I get a Broadcom BCM430N wireless card working?

Tags: wireless, broadcom

My acer computer with ubuntu12.10 can't connect the wifi. how can i do with this. i see the question at [Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4312](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312),the first answer said i can use b43-fwcutter and firmware-b43-lpphy-installer ,but there isn't a download link at https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/b43-fwcutter/,

Neither nor firmware-b43-lpphy-installer ,who has it.how can i do.

Answer (score 1):

You can find  `b43-fwcutter` and `firmware-b43-lpphy-installer` in Ubuntu Software Centre.

Just search for `b43` to find them, and click install.

[image: b43 in Software Centre]

I would recommend having a [look at this page](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Supported_devices) to make sure you are installing the correct package for your device.

Comment: i don't know, there is no BCM430N version! why?

Comment: mine is BCM430N, 430N NOT 4301...430N IS NOT INCLUDED IN THE LIST

Comment: To be honest I assumed you had mis-typed the model no. and provided the additional link to help. What are the outputs of the command given in the link " lspci -vnn -d 14e4: " or " lspci -nn | grep Network " as they should give precise details of your hardware.

Comment: my network card version is BCM430N!! i promise ,you can search it on google.there is no BCM430N.....

Comment: oh, i am sorry , my card no. is BCM43227. how can i do with it ...

Comment: i have no Cable network。how do i do ..give me a detail step..