# Wireless card not supported on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, wireless

Why doesn't Ubuntu 12.04 natively support any wireless interfaces I try? I've tried both BCM4312 and RT2870 chips. I've followed both of the manuals on this site, but none of them have been useful.

This is my last attempt to use Linux after trying to get used to it after 12 years.

Comment: Except for a few devices like Broadcom, most will work out of the box however there's good instructions for the getting the 3212 device working.  There's two parts to getting Wifi working: ensuring that it is recognised, then configuring it to work with your wifi router.

Comment: To solve this problem: [How to Install Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 4):

What's your problem?  12.04 supports the rt2860 out of the box, no longer needing the old rt2860sta driver from the staging area -- the driver to use is the rt2800pci (or ...usb depending upon your device.  The Broadcom 4312 runs fine with the b43 driver, all you need to do is supply the firmware with a package install of b43_fwcutter or one of the firmware-b43_installer packages.  If you are stuck trying to get older vendor supplied drivers to work, switch to the working, open source drivers.

Answer (score 3):

My B4312 runs great, Please see this question for more details:

> [Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4312](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312)