# i cant connect to my home wifi in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless

as it is a wpa,wpa2 personal connection but i cant change it in the network wireless setting ...It keeps on coming as a wep connection but when i type my network password the connect button on bottom of dialog box fades out.but when i add some more characters it fades in but with the correct password only we can connect so its useless..As i'm new to linux and want to be a linux user i expect answes from the pros...

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to add more information on your wireless device, type `lspci` in a terminal window (opened using Ctrl+Alt+T) and you'll get a list of your hardware, then post the hardware details related to your question as an edit to your original question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a pro but there may be issues with your particular wifi adapter. Please post the results of this command:

```
you@linux ~$ sudo lspci | grep 802.11
```

It should list your wifi device(s).

In particular there has been in the past issues with the Broadcom network controllers. There is a [community help wiki page on Broadcom wifi devices](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) and a quick search shows that there other users with [problems getting Broadcom wifi devices to work on 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312).

Hope that helps! It did for me. See [my post](http://poquitopicante.blogspot.com/2011/12/follow-pack.html) about it. I had very similar issues as you - greyed out "enable wifi", etc. In particular my solution (after searching the [ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/), ask ubuntu and [community help docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community)) was to remove the [STA drivers](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/broadcom-sta-common) using the Ubuntu Software Center, and installed the [b43 drivers](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/firmware-b43-installer) instead. But first I made sure that my wifi adapter was supported by b43 on the [linux wireless](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43) site.

Good Luck!