# ubuntu 12.10 wireless is not working

Tags: wireless, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)
>   [Wireless doesn’t work on a Broadcom BCM4312](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312)

I am new to Ubuntu. I had installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop. Wireless is not working. It is not detecting the available networks. I am able to connect through wire.

Please help me in connecting through wifi.

arun@arunan:~$ lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
```

arun@arunan:~$ sudo lshw -c network

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f69fc000-f69fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: a4:ba:db:de:ce:a2
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.2.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:45 ioport:de00(size=256) memory:f0010000-f0010fff memory:f0000000-f000ffff memory:f0020000-f003ffff
```

arun@arunan:~$ rfkill list all
arun@arunan:~$

The model is Dell Inpsiron 1440

Below are the results which I got when I boot through the live USB and connect to the wireless.

```
$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 01
       serial: 0c:60:76:65:ce:e2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=5.100.82.112 ip=192.168.2.10 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
       resources: irq:17 memory:f69fc000-f69fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: a4:ba:db:de:ce:a2
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:45 ioport:de00(size=256) memory:f0010000-f0010fff memory:f0000000-f000ffff memory:f0020000-f003ffff
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You'll need to specify which model of wireless hardware you have as each will have different problems. Please edit your question with your hardware details.

Comment: to get hardware details, open a terminal and execute the following commands, copy the output, edit your question and post them. commands - `lspci` , `sudo lshw -c network` , `rfkill list all` . You may include the make and model of your PC.

Comment: Follow answer of [Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4312](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312)

Comment: Hi Web-E, Many thanks for your quick help !! I followed the answer and did the same. I am still facing the same issue - unable to detect the wireless networks.

Comment: You can try running this command: `rfkill unblock all`, maybe your wireless is blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your hardware is a bit older; not yet supporting the latest operating systems.

You could install an older Windows driver and test if it works on Ubuntu.
(Ubuntu 10.04) https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/troubleshooting-wireless.html#troubleshooting-wireless-ndiswrapper

Here's some more information on installing Windows drivers, and also some information on particular hardware:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper

**UPDATE** I've come to find out that the Broadcom 4311 chip stopped working as late as Ubuntu 11.x, it might be the case that the Broadcom 4312 chip that you're using is defective on Ubuntu 12.x.
Try installing the following driver (`bcmwl-kernel-source`) according to the manual and see if it works:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: Thanks Zeelia, I am unable use the wireless network in windows too whereas I was able to use the wireless when I tried Ubuntu 12.10 through the USB device before installing it.

Comment: So you're saying that when you ran Ubuntu as a "LiveCD/LiveUSB" (trying without installing) it worked, but when you installed it, it stopped working? This could mean that there is a working driver on the installation disk. Boot into the installation disk and if the network is connected, run `sudo lshw -C network` and post the results.

Comment: **Also**, see the update I've done in my answer post.

Comment: `bcmwl-kernel-source
bcmwl-kernel-source: command not found`

Comment: That's because it is not a command itself; it's a package you must install. Follow the instructions on the manual I posted. The section that corresponds to your case is [3.1.2: 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) - 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal)](http://tinyurl.com/abeek59)

Comment: `sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma
FATAL: Module wl not found`  Please let me now how should I install this wl Module

Comment: wl is the official Broadcom driver. There are various options you can choose to apply on your system. Read the manual, and decide by yourself which method you want to apply. The method I suggested is the official Broadcom driver, but perhaps you'd be better off with an open source driver which (IMO) is easier to install. If you have any problems with that, we can take it from there.

Comment: Many Thanks Zeelia !! Now finally I am able to connect to the wireless network. :)

Comment: You're welcome :) It was mostly your own effort.

Answer (score 0):

This usually solves the problem, from ubuntu troubleshooting.

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/net-wireless.html

Comment: Thanks Alen. I tried the same, It says UNCLAIMED. It asks me to use windows drivers but my windows 7 wirless is not working too.

Comment: Changed link, it's for 12.10 now.